# ConnectionString with DAPPER ORM not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, connection-string, dapper

I created following Repository file

```
using Dapper;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ProjectName.Repository
{
    public class SMRTRepository : IDashboard
    {
        public SqlConnection con;
        //To Handle connection related activities
        private void connection()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
            con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        }

        .........
    }
}
```

Then In that project created a App.Config File to define connection string,

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=sa;Password=****;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.sqlclient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

but then when I run this , its not connecting to DB , In Server Explorer window in Visual Studio I can see connection string connecting to DB without Red icon

whats wrong in my approach

Comment: _Integrated Security = True_ or _User ID=...._ ? Choose one

Comment: @Steve I tried `Integrated Security = SSPI` then its not working also

Comment: providerName="System.Data.sqlclient"   -- remove this

Use below format

`"Server=servername;Database=dbName;User ID=sa;Password=pass"`
or
`"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True"`

Comment: If you use Integrated Security = True then your User ID and Password are ignored. Of course this means that SQLServer is able to recognize your windows user as a legitimate user of the database

Comment: @Steve what can I use here then `<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=sa;Password=****;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.sqlclient"/>`

Comment: And what is the error message received (including the InnerException message) ?

Comment: @Steve its null http://imgur.com/a/u3lej

Comment: Is it _con_ the same variable that you have instantiated in the _connection()_ method? Do you redeclare another _con_ variable that hides the one on the _connection_ method? By the way, I suggest to avoid global connection objects. Just return the _con_ initialized  in the _connection_ method and enclose it in a _using_ block

Comment: @Steve yes , here one `con` using , how to avoid global connection objects ? can I have example ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify both Integrated Security = True and an Sql User ID. As [explained by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) on the Integrated Security option line

> If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set
>   to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated
>   Security will be used.

This means that you have to have enabled the Windows Integration when you installed Sql Server and your current windows user is listed between the accepted users of that server.

Another possible problem is caused by some kind of mishandling of the global connection object. As a good practice it is better to avoid global disposable objects like a connection.

I would change your class to be

```
namespace ProjectName.Repository
{
    public class SMRTRepository : IDashboard
    {
        private SqlConnection OpenConnection()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            return con;
        }
        ....

        public IEnumerable<Something>Select(string queryFilter)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = this.OpenConnection())
            {
                return cnn.Query<Something>(queryFilter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you could also separate the two methods in different classes and use the first method as a static method that serves every other repository classes that you need to build. In this way there are no global objects around and the using block ensures a proper cleanup of your disposable objects also in case of exceptions.

Comment: So whats the connections string should use for your approach `<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBNAME; User ID = sa; Password = ****;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: I would just remove the User ID and Password part. But if you have installed locally on your PC the Sql Server Express that connection should work as expected. I would try to use the debugger to check if every part of this code returns the expected result. In particular the part where we try to read the connectionstring from the configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a sample code block from one of my project. Its working fine for me. Please refer

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            // Query
            string query = "Query";

            DynamicParameters dp = new DynamicParameters();
            dp.Add("@userName", userName, DbType.AnsiString);

            return connection.Query<Model>(query, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, param: dp);
        }
```

Comment: And why this answers the question?